# grpc server on Android

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to build a platform agnostic communication channel between a provider and consumer processes. Found grpc + protobuf to be a good option.

Is there an example or implementation of GRPC server (Java/C++) running on Android?
I am following grpc java server example to implement the server i

```
private class GrpcServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int port = 50051;
        Server server;
        try {
            server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
                    .addService(new GreeterImpl())
                    .build()
                    .start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private class GreeterImpl extends GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase {

    @Override
    public void sayHello(HelloRequest req, StreamObserver<HelloReply> responseObserver) {
        HelloReply reply = HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello " + req.getName()).build();
        responseObserver.onNext(reply);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional server found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-netty artifact
on executing new GrpcServerTask().execute();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Netty server on Android isn't really supported. Android's garbage collector and NIO support are both too poor for good Netty performance. Also some things are unlikely to work, like TLS. If it is just for testing on the newest Android release it may mostly work, but no guarantees that it works now or continues to work in the future.

With that in mind, make sure that you have a dependency on grpc-netty and try without ProGuard as a test. ProGuard's renaming and stripping both can cause trouble; you would need `-keepnames io.grpc.ServerProvider` and `-keep io.grpc.netty.NettyServerProvider` in your ProGuard rules, like [was done for client-side](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v0.15.0/examples/android/app/proguard-rules.pro).

C++ in another option. Client-side has been used on Android already, and I would expect server-side to function if you get client-side working. But I'm also not as aware of the C++ implementation.

Comment: Note: the Netty team has decided to officially support Android http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.1.html#wiki-h3-3

Comment: Is there any example how we can run gRPC server on Android, either using java or c++?